# The value of a <button>-element is not send along with the form

Tags: html, forms, button

I thought a [`<button>`-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) behaves like a normal `<input>`-element, as a button is attached to a form and can have a name and a value.

But when it comes to sending its value, it just won't do. This `<button>`'s value never gets through with the other form values:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <button type="button" id="fieldname" name="fieldname" value="">
            Click to select …
        </button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The `value`-attribute is set via JavaScript which works just fine.

Is there a way to handle this problem, without using an *extra hidden* `<input>`-element?
And could someone explain, why a `<button>` behaves like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buttons are only successful controls when they are used to submit the form.

Your button is of `type="button"` so it exists solely to hang JavaScript off. It will not submit the form.

If you change it to `type="submit"` (or remove the type attribute entirely since submit is the default), then it will submit the form when clicked, and be a successful control and its name and value will appear in the submitted data.

[image: Screenshot of Net tab]

Comment: That means, if I have multiple buttons, with *different* names and values in one form, only the one that **submits** the form is been send, right? And let's say I want to build a GUI with lots of buttons and I want to store the current state of the GUI somewhere: Then I have to grab them all, store their values in extra fields and submit them?

Comment: Yes and yes (or some other means of storing the state).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `<button>` element in an HTML form, different browsers may submit different values. Use `<input>` to create buttons in an HTML form. (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)

Why don't you use this :

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="button" id="fieldname" name="fieldname" value="Click to select …" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```